# XQuery difference between same function different implementation

Tags: xquery

Return the number of cycles:

```
let $bd := doc("document")
return count (  for $c in $bd//cycle
where $c[@id]
return $c
)
```

Every cycle has an ID, not important here but it is a must to specify it.
What is the difference between the above use of count and the below use of count?

```
let $bd := doc("document")
let $c := $bd//cycle[@id]
return count($c)
```

I dont know the difference between these 2 XQueries return same result but following the same pattern the next 2 queries should work but the 2nd one doesnt... Here they are:

The total of hours of modules which is above 100.

```
*Working query*
let $bd:=doc("document")
return sum (
for $m in $bd//module[@id]
where $m/hours>100
return $m/hours
)

*Not working query*
let $bd := doc("document")
for $c in $bd//module[@id]
where $c/hours>100
return sum($c/hours)
```

Id like to know why following the same "pattern" the second query is not working.
The output of the not working query is this one:

```
160 160 256 224 192 160
```

Its not the result i need, I want the sum of all them.

Comment: It is most likely that the second formulation of your first query would be more efficient as you are not iterating using a for loop, therefore it is easier for an implementation to optimise and exploit indexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first two expressions are functionally equivalent. The difference is the use of FLWOR vs. XPath to select your sequence.

In the second example, you are calling `sum()` on each item of the sequence (`$c/hours`), instead of on the sequence itself:

```
let $bd := doc("document")
return sum(
  for $c in $bd//module[@id]
  where $c/hours>100
  return $c/hours)
```

You could also use XPath:

```
let $bd := doc("document")
let $c := $bd//module[@id][hours>100]
return sum($c/hours)
```

Or similarly assign the result of the FLWOR to a variable and sum that:

```
let $bd := doc("document")
let $c := 
  for $m in $bd//module[@id]
  where $m/hours>100
  return $m/hours
return sum($c)
```

Comment: let $bd := doc("document")
let $c := $bd//module[@id][hours>100]
return sum($c/hours)    is there a way to place the hours>100 in a where clause?

Comment: @Alpha2k Like this? `sum(for $h in doc("document")//module[@id]/hours where ($h > 100) return $h)`